# graficar funcion y encontrar puntos optimos en Python(Sympy)

Tags: python, sympy

actualmente estoy encontrándome con un problema un tanto molesto, poseo un código que es para problemas de optimización, el código logra graficar las restricciones; sin embargo, no se me ocurre el cómo hacer para graficar los puntos de intersección de las desigualdades.

```
#llamado de librerias y del programa de lectura de sintaxis (parser)

from sintaxis import sintaxis
import sympy
from sympy import *


#Definicion variables, matrices y listas

valores_funcion = []
Valor_restricciones = []
x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
Lista_Inecuaciones = [x>=0,y>=0]


def igualacion(Funcion):

    verificador = sintaxis(Funcion)

    if (verificador[0][0][0][0] == "0") or (verificador[0][0][2][0] == "0"):
        
        #Solucion con un solo factor
        solution = solve(Funcion, x)
        Lista_Inecuaciones.append(solution.args[0])
        print("entrada 1")
        print(solution.args[0])
    else:
        #Solucion con dos factores
        solution = solve(Funcion, x)
        Lista_Inecuaciones.append(solution.args[1])
        print("entrada 2")
        print(solution.args[1])

def graficar(Funcion):
    #graficacion con inecuaciones ya resueltas

    Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones = And(*Lista_Inecuaciones)
    print(Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones)
    plot1 = plot_implicit(Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones, (x, -1, 10), (y, -1, 10), show=False)
    plot2 = plot_implicit(sympify(Funcion), line_color="red", show=False)
    plot1.append(plot2[0])
    plot1.show()

def funcion():
    #Funcion general, se encarga de pedir datos y correr el resto de codigo

    #Funcion = input("Ingrese la funcion en orden N*x + N*y <= N: ")
    
    Funcion = "30000*x + 50000*y"

    Restricciones = int(input("ingrese numero restricciones: "))

    for x in range(Restricciones):
        input_valor = input("Ingrese la "+str(x+1)+" restriccion: ")
        Valor_restricciones.append(input_valor)

    for i in range(len(Valor_restricciones)):
 
        igualacion(Valor_restricciones[i])
    graficar(Funcion) 


#llamado de funciones

funcion()
```

Ese es mi código actual, leyendo documentación había entendido que nsolve es para ecuaciones lineales y que existe solve_univariate_inequality, no obstante me arroja la función ya dada, cosa que ya hago y estoy buscando algún método o forma de que me tome los puntos exactos de las intersecciones entre esas inecuaciones.

Por otro lado, probé con gpt, y me arrojo dos cosas que sympy no era capaz de resolver eso (cosa que dudo) y un código que trata de recorrer los resultados, pero al no tener en todos la x o la y, este falla, por lo que lo descarte, entiendo como funciona matemáticamente esto, pero pasarlo a código no sé cómo, agradezco su ayuda y guía.